# How can I use an argument from xargs to evaluate another expression?

Tags: shell-script, find, xargs, basename, dirname

I would like to evaluate a `basename` expression given an argument from `xargs`.

I tested:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -I f cp f DIR_OUT/copied_$(basename f)
```

which gives `no file or directory` because `$(basename f)` was not evaluated correctly.

I may split it two steps: copying and changing the filename, but I would like to learn how to evaluate an expression with an argument from `xargs`.

Comment: When you press enter, the shell parses the line, see the `$()`, evaluates it, (resulting in `f`), start up the `find` and `xargs` with the resulting parameters. Quoting is needed to prevent that... But `xargs` is not a shell and does not understand things like `$()` on its own...

Answer (score 1):

The `$(basename f)` command substitution that you use in your command would be evaluated exactly once (yielding the string `f`), before the `xargs` command is even started.  This is why your code fails to copy the files to the correct names.

The "No such file or directory" error that you get is due to the `f` in `DIR_OUT/copied_f` being replaced by the pathnames of the files found by `find`.

---

A more robust way of doing the same thing,

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        cp "$pathname" "DIR_OUT/copied_${pathname##*/}"
    done' sh {} +
```

Or, with `xargs` while taking care to pass the found pathnames between `find` and `xargs` as nul-terminated strings:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 |
xargs -0 sh -c '
    for pathname do
        cp "$pathname" "DIR_OUT/copied_${pathname##*/}"
    done' sh
```

In both of these variations, we call a small in-line shell script that loops over the given pathnames and copies them to new names under the directory `DIR_OUT`.  The `${pathname##*/}` may be replaced by `$( basename "$pathname" )`.

Note that `-print0` (in `find`) and `-0` (in `xargs`) are non-standard, but commonly implemented.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: The `for` without `in ...;` is interesting... (It seems supported in `bash` and `dash`). OpenSolaris (k)sh seems to need a semicolon (or newline) (according to the [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1/sh/)). (The [POSIX docs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_03) does not seem to require it)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg The syntax is standard, but "relatively recent". Very old shells would not understand it. All shells that I have access to groks it correctly (bash, dash, zsh, yash, pdksh, ksh93). Yes, an older shell may well need a `;` before `do` (but would probably not require the full `for ... in "$@"; do`).

Comment: Even Solaris 10's `sh` (which is an actual Bourne shell, [seems to support it](https://www.unix.com/man-page/sunos/1/sh/)). I'm not sure about the semi-colon. It is nice to know about these (relatively obscure) shorthand versions...

Answer (score 1):

You need a small modification in your original command

```
find . -name '*.txt' | xargs -I f sh -c 'cp f DIR_OUT/copied_$(basename f)'
```

Answer (score 0):

To interpret the `$()`, you need to run a shell from `xargs`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51305211/1837991)

You should also be using null-deliminated output from find (when on a system that allows it), to prevent issues with problematic characters in filenames.

This should do what you want: (If somewhere without the null support, remove `-0` from `xargs` and replace `-print0` with `-print`)

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -n1 -r0 /bin/sh -c 'cp "$1" "DIR_OUT/copied_$(basename "$1")"' ''
```

`-type f` ensures that find only give file results
`-print0` make find print null terminated output
`-n1` ensures that `xargs` pass only one result to a process
`-r` tells `xargs` not to run stuff if there is no results
`-0` makes `xargs` accept null-terminated input

The command that is run is a shell with an inline script and one blank parameter (since that is how parameters are passed to `-c` scripts)

`xargs` pass the parameters to the `sh -c 'commands' ''`, which results in the first parameter being `$1` inside the -c. The single quotes bevents the calling shell from dealing with the `$()` and `$1`.

Comment: `"$@"` can be used as well, but that might require that the shell is `bash`